# Should I use Yahoo-Pipes to scrape the contents of a div?

Tags: screen-scraping, yahoo-pipes

Given:

- Url - http://www.contoso.com/search.php?q={param} returns:

  -html-
  --body-
  {...}
  ---div id='foo'-
  ----div id='page1'/-
  ----div id='page2'/-
  ----div id='page3'/-
  ----div id='pageN'/-
  ---/div-
  {...}
  --/body-
  -/html-

Wanted:

- The innerHtml of div id='foo' must be fetched by the client (i.e. Javascript).

  - It will be split into discrete items (i.e. div id='page1' to div id='pageN').
- API Throttling prevents server-side code from pre-fetching the data, so the parsing and manipulation burden must be placed on the client.

Question:

- Could Yahoo-Pipes help format the data for easier consumption?

  - The lack of a DOM parser gives me pause.
- Are there any existing pipes that could serve as an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) module, which allows you to fetch arbitrary URLs and then parse them with XPath. A sample YQL query:

```
select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=yhoo" and
  xpath='//div[@id="yfi_headlines"]/div[2]/ul/li/a'
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's doable with Y! Pipes. You only need two modules from the 'Operators section':

First "Sub Element" to get only the content.

Then just use the "Regex" module to extract the div content and get it through JSON from your site:

Search:

`^.*?<div id="foo">(.*?)</div>.*?$`

Replace:

$1