# Get web results from HttpClient for Android

Tags: java, android, httpclient, web-scraping

For example: Say I searched something on the [Walmart homepage](http://www.walmart.com). Like [this](http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?search_constraint=0&ic=48_0&search_query=ipod&Find.x=0&Find.y=0&Find=Find). How would I retrieve the information from the first product listed. Information like product name, price, details, rating, model. And how would I search in the box. The only way it seems like to me is to replace *http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?search_constraint=0&ic=48_0&search_query=**someProduct**&Find.x=0&Find.y=0&Find=Find*. Then replace someProduct with the seach and call it in an HttpClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its requires some Server side task. when search the with your url it should return the xml feed which contains what your are needed fields like name, price,etc.After that you can [parse that xml](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/) and achieve your target.

But its not possible for you to do that serverside work. you can use some [html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223458/smart-way-of-parsing-and-using-website-data) to do that.